# React Native, Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to run my react native app in emulator by using command `react-native run-android` but it's throwing that error

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 44s
info Connecting to the development server...
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync /Opt/Android/platform-tools/adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
The system cannot find the path specified.
error Failed to start the app. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: /Opt/Android/platform-tools/adb shell am start -n com.reactproject/com.reactproject.MainActivity
    at makeError (C:\Users\Danger World\ReactProject\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
```

I already setup my android studio and sdk manager, avd manager like it's shown in doc also  I already set path but it's still showing that error, anyone know why? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 31):

You can fix it by using the command :

```
react-native doctor
```

This command shows all issues that need to be fixed.

[image]

Press f to fix the issues and don't forget to restart your windows

And after then open the emulator before running your project.
Once emulator opened,
run command:
react-native run-android

After fixed:

[image]

Don't forget to give me an upvote if that's work.

Comment: Much appreciated. This helped me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 4):

In My Case, I have to re-run the command in the same terminal where you are trying to run **npx react-native run-android**

Step 1. paste the source command first

> source ~/.bash_profile OR source ~/.bashrc

Step 2. RUN Next command

> npx react-native run-android

Comment: Thanks but do i have to every time write this before step 2 ? is there any global way to fix this

Answer (score 3):

set your AVD manager path and JDK path like this  , also you have to add Android Home path
[image: Environment variables]